# aiohttp. Как добавить к существующему event loop aiohttp client session?

Tags: python, асинхронность, asyncio, event-loop

Всем добра.
Возникла проблема при получение данных на сервере aiohttp с другого портала, через клиент aiohttp.
Запускаю сервер со стандартными параметрами:

```
app = web.Application()
app.router.add_post('/rpc', rpc)
web.run_app(app, port=5000)
```

в route /rpc функция получает данные с другого сервера через aiohttp-клиент, пример из документации:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(client):
    async with client.get('http://python.org') as resp:
        assert resp.status == 200
        return await resp.text()

async def main(loop):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as client:
        html = await fetch(client)
        print(html)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

При обращении по адресу http://localhost:5000/rpc, вылетает 500 ошибка и в логах написано:

```
    raise RuntimeError('This event loop is already running')
RuntimeError: This event loop is already running
```

Я так понимаю, что запускаю еще один loop в уже запущенном loop (web.run_app)
Как возможно подружить клиента и сервера для совместной работы?

Comment: вы хотите в коде сервера вызвать `fetch()`?

Comment: Нет, в отдельном модуле.

Comment: в каком модуле не важно (код сервера можете по многим модулям раскидать -- как хотите). Запрос где вы хотите делать?

Comment: Да, в коде сервера. Но мне постоянно возвращается coroutine.
Я делаю запрос к Zabbix API, и что бы не возникало проблем с задержками при длительных запросах, то пытаюсь сделать код запроса к Zabbix асинхронным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import async_timeout
from aiohttp import web

async def fetch(session, url):
    with async_timeout.timeout(10):
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            return await response.text()

async def handle(request):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        html = await fetch(session, 'http://python.org')
        return web.Response(text=html)

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_get('/', handle)

web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

Comment: явно не обязательно loop передавать (у вас только один цикл событий здесь)

Comment: @jfs я специально внёс в исходные примеры с первой страницы документации минимальные изменения.

Comment: К чему вы это упомянули? Не нужно слепо код копировать, не понимая что он делает.

Comment: Что касаемо необязательности передачи loop, то Светлов говорит на каждом семинаре об явном указании loop. Вроде как "python way" - явное лучше, чем неявное.

Comment: @Aleksey async метод всегда исполняется извне (сам по себе его вызов просто генератор создаёт). Если у вас нет намерения несколько циклов событий использовать, то явно передавать цикл совершенно излишне,  когда вы работаете на уровне async/await абстракций (цикл это то что вашу async функцию исполняет). Мусорить в каждой функции не нужно. Более наглядно это видно в curio, trio библиотеках. Не следует слепо советам следовать, которые могут быть хороши в одних обстоятельствах, но не применимы в других. В Питоне 3.6 гарантируется, что asyncio.get_event_loop() возвращает цикл используемый await.

Comment: @jfs большое спасибо за объяснение. За коммент большой и жирный плюс поставил, если бы здесь такое возможно было.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov рекомендует передавать loop явно только в тестах.

Answer (score 0):

Можно инициализировать ClientSession один раз:

```
from aiohttp import web, ClientSession


async def fetch(session: ClientSession, url: str) -> str:
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text()


async def handle(request: web.Request) -> web.Response:
    html = await fetch(request.app['session'], 'http://google.com')
    return web.Response(text=html)


async def init_session(app: web.Application) -> None:
    app['session'] = ClientSession()


async def close_session(app: web.Application) -> None:
    await app['session'].close()


def init_app() -> web.Application:
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get('/', handle)
    app.on_startup.append(init_session)
    app.on_cleanup.append(close_session)
    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    web.run_app(init_app())
```

aiohttp==3.5.4